# Force core data to fulfill faults on a queue?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm managing a core data store on multiple threads and I've had success avoiding deadlocks by doing most of my database calls on a serial queue that I've created - except for when core data fulfills faults.

I can't tell if there's a way to tell core data to only do operations like faulting on a specific serial queue to avoid this. My other option is simply not returning faults, but my sense is that this should be avoidable.

How can I force core data to access the database only via my serial queue?

Comment: How are you managing your threads? It seems to me that if you handle CoreData with threads as shown in the docs then you shouldn't run into this problem.

Comment: What part of the docs explains what happens on faults with threads? I'm not sure I've seen it.

Comment: I just mean how are you handling CoreData in general. Are your using parent/child contexts with `performBlock`?

Comment: Lots of dispatch_async with proper isolation of managedobjectcontext between main and background threads, syncing between the two, passing managedobjectids rather than objects, etc.

Comment: No offense, but that sounds painful. If you can, I would recommend using parent/child contexts. Here is a good blog post about it: [Multi-Context CoreData](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/). Try to build a small test app using this technique and see if it solves your issues.

Comment: @sosborn I'll check out parent/child contexts, I hadn't heard of that before. Otherwise I'm doing the standard stuff described in the beginning of that article.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force faults on specific queue for all CoreData requests. You have to force faults on objects using

```
[context refreshObject:objectToBEFaulted mergeChanges:NO]
```

before accessing any attribute of the object.